# Wordpress Site Php Error Message

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to visit my wordpress blog, I get this error message:

```
Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer in /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 894    
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/object-cache.php:894) in /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/themes/boombox/includes/rate-and-vote-restrictions/vote/class-boombox-vote-restriction.php on line 193
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/object-cache.php:894) in /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/themes/boombox/includes/rate-and-vote-restrictions/vote/class-boombox-vote-restriction.php on line 193
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-content/object-cache.php:894) in /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/65/3865365/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179
```

Comment: The other errors are cascading effect, the first error seems to derive from a caching issue, try clearing your wordpress cache

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Godaddy Managed WordPress side.

I got this fix after several hours with GD support. As mentioned above there is a problem with the GD caching feature, until they fix it you can do this!

**SOLUTION (for Godaddy Managed WordPress Sites):**

1) FTP into your wp-content folder.

2) rename “object-cache.php” to “object-cache-DISABLED.php”

3) flush your site cache using the GD menu function at the top of your WP admin CP.